# Cannot assign any value greater 255 OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

I tried to create a histogram but I cant assign any value greater 255, if it over example 256 it will be 0, and so on. How can I fix it?

```
    histMatrix = Mat(nChannelSource, 256, CV_16SC1);
    uchar* pRowHistMatrix = histMatrix.data;
    for (int y = 0; y < nChannelSource; y++, pRowHistMatrix += histMatrix.step[0]) {
        uchar* pColHistMatrix = pRowHistMatrix;

        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++, pColHistMatrix += histMatrix.step[1]) {
            ((signed short*)pColHistMatrix)[0] = 256;
        }
    }

    pRowHistMatrix = histMatrix.data;
    for (int y = 0; y < nChannelSource; y++, pRowHistMatrix += histMatrix.step[0]) {
        uchar* pColHistMatrix = pRowHistMatrix;

        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++, pColHistMatrix += histMatrix.step[1]) {

            std::cout << (int)pColHistMatrix[0] << " ";
        }
    }
```

Comment: you're using an `unsigned char` which is usually only 8-bit so can't hold values larger than 255

Comment: I tried CV_16SC1 and it has the same result

Comment: The data type stored in the matrix is 16-bit but you are casting to `uchar*`

Comment: Thank you too much, have a nice day. Its really hard for newbie, I will fix it soon

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as an **answer** -- do not add it to your **question**. Rolled back the offending edit.

Comment: Yeah thank you, I thought it allowed sry about that

Comment: first you should remove all that pointer arithmetic and use the `histMatrix.at<short>(i,j)` method to access the matrix...

Comment: I don't want to use this method, my teacher said it slow than use pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give the solution for someone have the same bug like me

The error is uchar* only handle 8 bit of a variable, and when we move n byte toward we must devide for sizeof(type), here is singed short

```
    histMatrix = Mat(nChannelSource, 256, CV_16SC1);

    signed short* pRowHistMatrix = (signed short*)histMatrix.data;
    for (int y = 0; y < nChannelSource; y++, pRowHistMatrix += histMatrix.step[0] / sizeof(signed short)) {
        signed short* pColHistMatrix = pRowHistMatrix;

        for (int x = 0; x < 256; x++, pColHistMatrix += histMatrix.step[1] / sizeof(signed short)) {
            pColHistMatrix[0] = 256;
        }
    }
```

Comment: and what's the *answer part* in this piece of code that looks very similar to the question's code?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).